# Send an email using "Flow Core Action: Send Email" to a Public group and a email id field from formula

Tags: visual-workflow, send-email

We have an Object XYZ which is related to standard Case object. It is a child object and has Lookup to Case. Whenever a record of this child object XYZ is created we want to send an email to below recipients,

- Public Group
- Case Owner

What have I tried so far,

- We tried with email alert, while sending to Public group is possible,
  Case owner is not listed in recipients.
- We are trying with **Flow Core Action: Send Email**, But even there I
  cannot find public group as    recipients. So I will have to fetch
  group by name, then group    members, create a collection of email
  ids and then pass that to    Recipents list of Send Email action. OR
  I will have to create an Apex    action to fetch the recipient email
  address from Public group.

Is there any simpler way to achieve this?